# How to verify whether a value is from a particular table in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is code snippet of my HTML page:

```html
<div id="top">
            <button type="button" name="ptmBtn" id="ptmBtn">PTM</button>
</div>
<div id="bottomleft">
    <b>Contact List</b>
        <table id="cntList">
   <tr>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"> </td>
    <td> Aniruddh </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"> </td>
    <td> Ajay <td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"> </td>
    <td> Vijay </td>
   </tr>
        </table>
</div>
<div id="bottomRight">
    <b>Group List</b>
        <table id="grpList">
   <tr>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"> </td>
    <td> Group1 </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"> </td>
    <td> Group2 <td>
   </tr>
        </table>
</div>
```

I am developing a Web application where I send messages to users by the push of a button. I have two HTML tables on my page namely Contacts with "id"="cntList" and Groups "id"="grpList"; where both tables will have names and a checkbox corresponding to them.

When I click on some contact in Contacts table or a group in the Group table, my code should understand whether it is from a Contacts table or it is a Group table and call the function to send the message accordingly.

I am getting how to start with JQuery in this?

Comment: Can you show us some of your code and what you've tried?  At least your HTML code.

Comment: 1 - attach a listener to checkboxes - use jquery's "closest" function to find the closest table - voilà - you now know which table the checkbox is in ... or 2 - attach a listener to each checkbox in cntList - the listener knows which table it's listening to, repeat for grpList ... separate listeners will know which table they are listeners for as if by majicks

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the `id` of the clicked parent `table` element  within event handler by checking the `.id` property of `this`, or `event.currentTarget` using `.closest()` with `table[id$=List]` as selector passed, `.attr()` with `"id"` as parameter

```js
var selector = "table[id$=List]";
$(selector + " :checkbox").click(function(event) {
  console.log($(this).closest(selector).attr("id"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="top">
  <button type="button" name="ptmBtn" id="ptmBtn">PTM</button>
</div>
<div id="bottomleft">
  <b>Contact List</b>
  <table id="cntList">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>Aniruddh</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>Ajay
        <td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>Vijay</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="bottomRight">
  <b>Group List</b>
  <table id="grpList">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>Group1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>Group2
        <td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This is how I would do it.

Comment: wouldn't that attach the click event to the table? as the question states the tables have id's of cntList and grpList not the checkboxes - that's the biggest problem with a question that has absolutely no code

Comment: I know @guest271314, I did mention that :p

Comment: @guest271314 - I personally don't care :p but I see you've used .closest (as I suggested in a comment I was posting at the same time :p )

Comment: @JaromandaX Had navigated away from this page. Had not read your comment. Though, yes, an appropriate suggestion.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you used my comment, I think I posted at almost the same time you edited :p